# Displaying text in UILabel in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

OK. What's wrong with my code?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    lblResult = [UILabel alloc];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 lblResult.text = @"BlahBlah";
}
```

I linked lblResult to Label object in IB well. But the label only shows the default text. Where's my BlahBlah??

And when the default string I set in the IB actually set to lblResult??

The reason that BlahBlah string is not displyed is I guess because lblResult.text is over-written by default string specified from IB. Just my guess.

Can anyone make me clear with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already made all of the correct connections from your `IBOutlet`s to Interface Builder, they will be automatically initialized for you. You shouldn't be re-initializing the object at all. (As a side point, you weren't fully initializing it).

So get rid of the initialization code in `-viewDidLoad` and it should work.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  lblResult.text = @"BlahBlah";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I mean isn't that supposed to display "BlahBlah" instead of default string from IB?

Comment: @SeniorLee, Yes. It should change the text, does it not?

Comment: NO, That's what I'm asking. I want to set another string to it but it doesn't work. ;(

Comment: @SeniorLee It must be that your IB setup is incorrect, because that code should work.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the frame to your label

**Example 1**

lblResult  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 10, 180, 20)];

**Example 2**

lblResult  = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblResult.frame = CGRectMake(75, 10, 180, 20);

or Adding color

lblResult  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 10, 180, 20)];

lblResult.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];

lblResult.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

lblResult.text = @"BlahBlah";